# JavaScript remove parameter from URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove parameter from URL.
I have this URL http://localhost/?page=test&id=190603|190629

```
<button onclick="removeId(190603)">Remove ID</button>
<button onclick="removeId(190629)">Remove ID</button>
```

How to do when click on button that id be removed from the url address and reload address without ID I've removed?

Comment: Umm... What? `When` you want to remove it?

Comment: It appears you've forgotten to include a [mcve] of [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com) and what you were struggling with. As such this question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Comment: This is not clear. On click you want to remove the id or replacing the id 190603 by 190629 ? What do you mean by refresh the page?

Comment: @Dimava When I click on link http://localhost/?page=test&id=190603 or http://localhost/?page=test&id=190603

Comment: @derloopkat When i click on http://localhost/?page=test&id=190603 or http://localhost/?page=test&id=190629 to reveme this id(that i click) from this url http://localhost/?page=test&id=190603|190629. If i click http://localhost/?page=test&id=190603 this url, the id must be removed from this url http://localhost/?page=test&id=190603|190629 and result should be http://localhost/?page=test&id=190629.

Comment: Update the question itself with an understandable description and what you have tried to make this work

Comment: @charlietfl okay.

Comment: @charlietfl i update my question. I hope now it is more clear what I want.

Comment: not really....before you were showing `<a>` tag with  href. you also haven't shown anything regarding any attempts to solve your problem. writing a good question takes a bit of effort and needs to be clear and concise

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just trying... (this was for prev version of question)

```js
s=location.search||$('tag').text();
m=s.match(/id=([\d|]*)/);
if(m && m[1] && m[1].indexOf('|')>-1)
m[1].split('|').forEach(function(e){
document.write('<a href=http://localhost/?page=test&id='+s.replace(new RegExp('(^|[|])'+e+'(?=$|[|])'),'')+'">Remove '+e+' id from url</a><br>')
});
//else document.write('nop!')

document.write('<hr>');

// single id test:
s='?page=test&id=190603'
m=s.match(/id=([\d|]*)/);
if(m && m[1] && m[1].indexOf('|')>-1)
m[1].split('|').forEach(function(e){
document.write('<a href=http://localhost/?page=test&id='+s.replace(new RegExp('(^|[|])'+e+'(?=$|[|])'),'')+'">Remove '+e+' id from url</a><br>')
});
else document.write('nop!')

document.write('<hr>');

// no id test:
s='?page=test'
m=s.match(/id=([\d|]*)/);
if(m && m[1] && m[1].indexOf('|')>-1)
m[1].split('|').forEach(function(e){
document.write('<a href=http://localhost/?page=test&id='+s.replace(new RegExp('(^|[|])'+e+'(?=$|[|])'),'')+'">Remove '+e+' id from url</a><br>')
});
else document.write('nop!')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
location.search=<tag color="red">?page=test&amp;id=190603|764583|87436835|846345</tag><br>
```

Okay, i got some lulz.

Ow, and answer for updated question: Make the same (as above) thing on php

Comment: @didson, any comments?

Comment: This is exactly what I want, thank you very much.
Just one extra thing when you remove the first link remains |